# aligning the xml document

Tags: php, xml, data-structures, domdocument

i'm inserting the data into an xml file using php domdocument. however when i open the xml file, the data is displayed in a single line:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root><activity>swimming</activity><activity>jogging</activity></root>
```

how do i align it programmatically like this?

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root>
  <activity>swimming</activity>
  <activity>jogging</activity>
</root>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use this function

```
function pretty_xml($string) {
  $xml = DOMDocument::loadXML($string);
  $xml->formatOutput = true; 
  return $xml->saveXML();
}
```

Comment: where do i call this function?

Comment: Put this before you send your xml to browser. If you already use $xml->saveXML() (from domdocument) to output xml then just put $your_document->formatOutput = true; before sending xml to browser.

Comment: The important feature here, as jcubic's last comment suggests, is the DOMDocument '$formatOutput' property, which can be set at any time after the object is created (i.e., you don't necessarily have to use it inside a user function. See the documentation for DOMDocument.)

Answer (score 1):

Use newlines and tabs with "\n" and "\t" respectively, in double quotes in your PHP code.

Comment: tried this. when i click enter to insert the data, the page goes blank instead of displaying the data. and in the xml file, while it created the nodes, they are empty.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to display it in easily readable form, http://gdatatips.blogspot.com/2008/11/xml-php-pretty-printer.html